# In the Kurukṣetra war, did anyone attempt to kill Kṛṣṇa and end the war instantly?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, arjuna, war

In the Kurukṣetra war, we often hear of great one-on-one battles between Arjuna & Bhīṣma, Arjuna & Droṇa, Bhīma & Karṇa, Arjuna & Karṇa, etc.

Since Kṛṣṇa was performing the role of charioteer for Arjuna, did anyone attempt to kill Kṛṣṇa and end the war instantly?

Were most of the Kauravas, Bhīṣma, Droṇa, Karṇa etc. aiming their astras and śastras only at Arjuna?

**Or was Kṛṣṇa ever the direct target of their weapons? If not, why?**

I'm assuming killing the charioteer and those who protect the chariot (foot soldiers) was all fair game in the Kurukṣetra war.

Comment: I think Srutayudha tried to do just that.

Comment: Some warriors aimed their fierceful arrows at krishna. I know particularly Bhishma shot arrows at at a place where krishna's fingers and nails meet. It caused pain to Him. He changed the direction of his chariot or turned himself accordingly. This is said in Andhra mahabharatam.

Comment: warriors shot arrows at Krishna like any other enemy charioteer, but as I know, Karna was trying to kill Arjuna and Krishna together

Comment: @GabrielAlexanderGonzalezAgu If you have the correct reference, you can post an answer.